# Kill Particular Instance of an .exe by name using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am attempting to use powershells'

```
Stop-Process -Name "notepad.exe"
```

Type command to kill, in the above case, all instances of notepad.exe even if I had 10 notepad files open.

I could of course use:

```
Stop-Process -Id 3952
```

To kill a particular instance of it, but if I were to then re-open all 10 notepad files the PID's would have changed. I can see in task manager each instance of notepad has a different process name, a name that will not change when I re-open it:

[image]

Is there a way, using a powershell script, to specifically kill "Notes 2" for example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MainWindowTitle` property returned by `Get-Process` to do this.  For example:

```
Get-Process |
    Where-Object MainWindowTitle -eq 'Notes 2 - Notepad' |
        Stop-Process -Force
```

Of course, if you had the same document open in more than one Notepad instance, they would have the same title and you'd be back to your original problem where you can't tell them apart.

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible to achieve this in a batch script or does something like this require powershell?